# make command needs jni_md.h from java include, but I don't have it

Tags: java, linux

I am going to install JZMQ. After I run the "make" command, error happens
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h:45:10: fatal error: 'jni_md.h' file not found`

But there is a file named "jni.h" this path.
What should I do。

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that `jni_md.h` is missing ... not `jni.h`.

Check that `jni_md.h` exists, work out what its path is.  Then look at the `#include` directives in the `jni.h` file to figure out how it is being included.

I suspect that you will find that the problem is something to do with the include path as specified on the compiler command line.  Examine the `makefile` for JZMQ to see what "-I" options are used, and also review the build instructions.

Comment: I have checked , jni.h include jni_md.h, BUT there is no jni.h in this path, I trying to copy one, but failed, I don't understand   " Examine the makefile for JZMQ to see what "-I" options are used, and also review the build instructions.",can you explain it, thank you very much

Comment: Sorry ... what don't you understand.  Do you know what a "Makefile" is?  Do you know what "make" does?  Did you read the build instructions?  (The README file?  https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/README.md)  This is all pretty basic!